# Memoize a function of type () -> 'a

Tags: f#, unit-type

[This memoize function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx) fails on any functions of type `() -> 'a`  at runtime with a Null-Argument-Exception.

```
let memoize f =
    let cache = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary()
    fun x ->
        if cache.ContainsKey(x) then 
            cache.[x]
        else 
            let res = f x
            cache.[x] <- res
            res
```

Is there a way to write a memoize function that also works for a `() -> 'a` ?

(My only alternative for now is using a `Lazy` type. calling `x.Force()` to get the value.)

Comment: Memoize is generally used to cache some computation on an argument where the argument is used as the lookup key. `Lazy` is the right tool in this case.

Comment: You _could_ wrap `lazy`, something like this: `let memoize f = let result = lazy (f()) in fun () -> result.Value`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why the function fails is that F# represents unit `()` using `null` of type `unit`. The dictionary does not allow taking `null` values as keys and so it fails.

In your specific case, there is not much point in memoizing function of type `unit -> 'a` (because it is better to use `lazy` for this), but there are other cases where this would be an issue - for example `None` is also represented by `null` so this fails too:

```
let f : int option -> int = memoize (fun a -> defaultArg a 42)
f None
```

The easy way to fix this is to wrap the key in another data type to make sure it is never `null`:

```
type Key<'K> = K of 'K
```

Then you can just wrap the key with the `K` constructor and everything will work nicely:

```
let memoize f =
    let cache = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary()
    fun x ->
        if cache.ContainsKey(K x) then 
            cache.[K x]
        else 
            let res = f x
            cache.[K x] <- res
            res
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Dictionary(HashIdentity.Structural)`?

Comment: Ain't it creates an own instance of `cache` dictionary for each function defined via call to `memoize`? Only because of this multiple keys `K <null>` may exist for `unit->'a` without a clash. As functions do not share the common cache, then any literal may play the role of the key and the whole arrangement effectively mimicks `lazy` approach.

Comment: @Gene memoize returns a function that closes over its own instance of Dictionary. memoize's signature is

  `f:('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b) when 'a : equality`

so the function that it returns is

  `'a -> 'b`

It's the returned function that you use to memoize values. E.g.,
  `let m = memoize (fun x -> x + 1);;`
gives
  `val m : (int -> int)`

Comment: @CurtNichols: Exactly to the point I've made - each function returned from `memoize` closes over own instance of `cache` having one <key,value> pair at most. Use of `Dictionary` just for persisting of one `value` is IMO an overkill, also the `key` is not needed at all, using a `bool` `filled` state indicator instead would be sufficient.

Comment: @Gene Belitski, the dictionary is not created by the function returned, but by the original call to `memoize`. Typical usage: call `memoize` once to create memoizing function `m` (the dictionary is created by `memoize` and closed over by function `m`); call `m` multiple times and it will cache multiple entries in the dictionary. If you modify the `fun x ->` expression to print before returning (`printfn "Cache has %d elements" cache.Count`) you'll see that the dictionary does contain multiple elements--because the dictionary is created by `memoize`, not by the function that `memoize` returns.

Comment: Better yet, here's a walkthrough in the F# Interactive window: https://gist.github.com/curtnichols/7938520

Comment: @CurtNichols: The point somehow is getting missing that the question is about specific group of functions having signature `unit -> 'a`, i.e. one and only one acceptable argument of type `unit`. Which, in turn, translates into `cache` having one entry at most within each function's closure.

Answer (score 6):

I just found that the last memoize function [on the same website](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx) using `Map` instead of `Dictionary` works for  `'a Option -> 'b` and `() -> 'a` too:

```
let memoize1 f =
    let cache = ref Map.empty

    fun x ->
        match cache.Value.TryFind(x) with
        | Some res -> res
        | None ->
            let res = f x
            cache.Value <- cache.Value.Add(x, res)
            res
```

Answer (score 2):

Memoization having a pure function (not just of type `unit -> 'a`, but any other too) as a lookup key is impossible because functions in general do not have equality comparer for the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844043/are-two-functions-equal).

It may seem that for this specific type of function `unit -> 'a` it would be possible coming up with a custom equality comparer. But the only approach  for implementing such comparer beyond extremes (reflection, IL, etc.) would be *invoking* the lookup function as `f1 = f2 iff f1() = f2()`, which apparently nullifies any performance improvement expected from memoization.

So, perhaps, as it was already noted, for this case optimizations should be built around `lazy` pattern, but not `memoization` one.

UPDATE: Indeed, after second look at the question all talking above about functions missing equality comparer is correct, but not applicable, because [memoization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx) happens within each function's individual `cache` from the closure. On the other side, for this specific kind of functions with signature `unit->'a`, i.e. at most single value of argument, using `Dictionary` with most one entry is an overkill. The following similarly stateful, but simpler implementation with just one memoized value will do:

```
let memoize2 f =
    let notFilled = ref true
    let cache = ref Unchecked.defaultof<'a>
    fun () ->
        if !notFilled then
            cache := f ()
            notFilled := false
        !cache
```

used as `let foo = memoize2(fun () -> ...heavy on time and/or space calculation...)`
with first use `foo()` performing and storing the result of calculation and all successive `foo()` just reusing the stored value.

Answer (score -1):

Solution with mutable dictionary and single dictionary lookup call:

`let memoize1 f =
    // printfn "Dictionary"
    let cache = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary()
    fun x ->
        let result, value = cache.TryGetValue(x)
        match result with
        | true -> value
        | false ->
            // printfn "f x"
            let res = f x
            cache.Add(x, res)
            res`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem posed in the question.  `memoize1 (fun () -> 1) ()` fails with an `ArgumentNullException`, too, for the same reason.