# How is removeEventListener implemented?

Tags: javascript, dom

According to another stack**overflow** question, "[Are two functions equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844043/are-two-functions-equal)", it is impossible to verify if one function equals another.

This has me wondering how `target.removeEventListener(type, listener)` is implemented.

Observe my sample code:

```
function eventHandler() {
    alert("hello!");
    document.removeEventListener("click", eventHandler);
}
document.addEventListener("click", eventHandler);
```

When I click anywhere in the document an alert box will pop up and show me "hello!". When I dismiss the alert box and click anywhere in the document again, nothing happens.

I can of course register multiple listeners on the same target for the same event. **I can even register multiple listeners with the same name**.

How does it work?

Comment: All you're doing here is throwing around a refernece to a function. There's no function comparison going on so I'm not sure what you're driving at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell if two **different** functions are equivalent, but you can tell if two variables **reference the same function**. These are 2 different concepts:

```js
 function add(a,b) {
   return a+b;
 }
 function add2(a,b) {
   return a+b;
 }
    
 var myAddFn=add;
    
 console.log(myAddFn===add) //true
 console.log(myAddFn===add2) //false
```

Then, if the removeEventListener method has a list of event handlers for a given event, it can just go through them and removing the required one